# What to include in WHERE clause to show previous week of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a stored procedure for an SSRS report and one of the criteria is to show the data from the previous week. I've tried multiple different things in my WHERE clause to show the previous week and I can't find one that returns any records.

I've tried `Datepart (w,-1,st.startdate)`, `DATEDIFF`, `DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE() - 7)` and others, below is what I'm currently trying which also does not return any records.

```
DECLARE @EndDate    DATETIME

SET @StartDate  = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 7, GETDATE()), 0)
SET @EndDate    = GETDATE()

    SELECT  sfd.SalesForecastID,
            sf.StartDate,
            sf.EndDate, 
            sf.[Description],
            CASE
                WHEN sf.StatusID = 1 THEN 'Open'
                WHEN sf.StatusID = 2 THEN 'Closed'
            END AS 'Status',
            pm.Generic,
            pm.SubGeneric,
            pm.SKU AS 'PartNumber', 
            sfd.ProposedVolume,
            sfd.EstimatedValue,
            sfd.MonthlyRunRate,
            sfd.ProductNotes
    FROM    [ForestDBDev].[dbo].[SalesForecastDetail] sfd
    INNER JOIN  [ForestDBDev].[dbo].[SalesForecast] sf      ON sf.SalesForecastID = sfd.SalesForecastID
    INNER JOIN  dbo.OrdPart op                              ON op.OrdPart_ID      = sfd.PartID          COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    INNER JOIN  [ForestDBDev].[ProductDB].[PartMaster] pm   ON op.PartNum         = pm.SKU              COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE sf.CreatedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: It returns no records. I've manually changed a record to a CreatedDate of the 15th of May and it is not returned by the query.

Comment: If it returns no **rows** then either the `WHERE` filtered out the data, or there were no rows returned from the `INNER JOIN`(s).

Comment: That between is going to cause you some serious challenges. You made the start date not include the time portion but the end date does. Using between is challenging, but with dates it is really difficult. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: What does `from the previous week` mean? Exactly 168 hours ago until now? 7 days ago until now? Last Sunday at midnight to Saturday at 11:59:59.9999999? Something else?

Comment: Does it return any rows if you comment out the WHERE clause?  If so, are the rows that you expect to be returned in there?  If not, then as @Larnu says, there's probably some problem with the JOIN conditions, try changing them to LEFT JOINs instead and see what it takes to get the rows you are looking for to show up in the output.  Then try reapplying the WHERE condition.